# C# Linq group rows with unique value

Tags: c#, linq

Given a datatable with the following rows.

```
POLICY START_DT     END_DT        AMOUNT  TYPE

1000   08/01/2017   09/01/2017   -10.00   A
1000   08/01/2017   09/01/2017    30.00   C
```

Expected Result:

```
POLICY START_DT      END_DT       AMOUNT  TYPE

1000   08/01/2017    09/01/2017   20.00   A
```

I want to always take the first TYPE value and apply to the grouped rows

What I have so far:

```
var results = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              group row by new
              {
                 Policy = row.Field<int>("POLICY"),
                 StartDt = row.Field<string>("START_DT"),
                 EndDt = row.Field<string>("END_DT"),
                 Type = row.Field<string>("TYPE")
              } into groupings
              select new
              {
                 groupings.Key.Policy,
                 groupings.Key.StartDt,
                 groupings.Key.EndDt,
                 groupings.Key.Type,
                 TotalAmount = groupings.Sum(t => t.Fields<decimal>("AMOUNT"))
              }
```

Comment: I think it's a mistake to use `TYPE` in the anonymous object you are grouping by....this way each row becomes its own group

Comment: Are start and end dates going to be the same or each policy?

Comment: Yes the dates will be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include the Type in the grouping

```
var results = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
          group row by new
          {
             Policy = row.Field<int>("POLICY"),
             StartDt = row.Field<string>("START_DT"),
             EndDt = row.Field<string>("END_DT"),                 
          } into groupings
          select new
          {
             Policy = groupings.Key.Policy,
             StartDt = groupings.Key.StartDt,
             EndDt = groupings.Key.EndDt,
             Type = groupings.OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("TYPE")).First().Field<string>("TYPE"),
             Amount = groupings.Sum(t => t.Fields<decimal>("AMOUNT"))
          };
```

Comment: yeah, sorting the `groupings` to get the "first" type is the idea I missed, but I still don't know if the alphabetical order is the one OP needs...

Comment: @RenéVogt yeah that makes sense. OP would need to clarify that.

Comment: Rene, you are correct. This is what I was looking for. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `TYPE` as grouping criteria. So leave that out of your anonmyous grouping type.

To get the `TYPE` value of the first row you can later read that from the first entry in `groupings`:

```
var results = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              group row by new
              {
                 Policy = row.Field<int>("POLICY"),
                 StartDt = row.Field<string>("START_DT"),
                 EndDt = row.Field<string>("END_DT")
              } into groupings
              select new
              {
                 groupings.Key.Policy,
                 groupings.Key.StartDt,
                 groupings.Key.EndDt,
                 groupings.First().Field<string>("TYPE"),
                 TotalAmount = groupings.Sum(t => t.Fields<decimal>("AMOUNT"))
              }
```

---

But I have to admit that I'm **not sure** if this will always take the **first row's `TYPE`** value, for whatever first means, as I'm not sure if `GroupBy` keeps the order of elements.